# Where is my Hair?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I noticed that I was playing terraria on my android mobile device that, after wearing changing my vanity items from the familiar set to other vanity items  for a while and then changing back to the familiar set that my **hair** went **missing**. does anyone know what happened?

Comment: Probably just a simple visual bug. Try saving and exiting, then reloading the world? Should force the game to render your hair.